# What's the real meaning of 'n' in complexity analysis

Tags: algorithm

As far as I am concerned, in the big-O notation, when we conclude that the time/space complexity of a certain algorithm is, say, O(n), we are saying that the relationship between the 'size' of time and extra space we need to realise the algorithm and the 'size' of the data we will be dealing with is linear. And the 'size' of data is the number of its atomic elements, the range of their values is out of our concern in this scenario.

Now, assume that we are dealing with some 'character frequency' problem. And the input strings will consist of only English lowercase characters. It's very intuitive to use Hash Table to tackle such problems. However, I want to use an array with 26 slots(i.e., constant space) to stimulate a Hash Table.

Since the size of the array is fixed no matter how long the input string will be, it makes sense to say that the space complexity is O(1).

However, the size of the array is still dependent upon some aspects of the input data (the range, in this case), though not the size of it. So, given that, it seems like that we can not say the space complexity is O(1).

So, my question is, What's the real meaning of 'n' in terms of complexity analysis. And what's the space complexity in the mentioned scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In complexity analysis, the variable 'n' represents a property of the input that influences the algorithm's performance.
The specific meaning of 'n' depends on the algorithm being analyzed, the assumptions made about the input, and other factors related to the problem domain or the implementation details.

---

For instance, let's examine sorting algorithms.

In the case of the [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) algorithm, which has a time complexity of O(n log n), 'n' signifies the number of elements in the input array.

On the other hand, in the [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) algorithm, the time complexity is O(n + k).
Assuming the input consists of natural numbers, 'n' refers to the number of elements in the input, while 'k' represents the maximum possible value among the input elements.

---

Now, let's consider matrix addition.

If we assume that the two matrices being added are square, the time complexity is O(n^2), where 'n' denotes the order of the matrix. Without this assumption, the time complexity becomes O(nm), with 'n' and 'm' representing the number of rows and columns in the matrices, respectively.

---

As demonstrated, the meaning of 'n' in complexity analysis relies on various factors such as the algorithm, and input properties.
To conduct a thorough complexity analysis, it is crucial to identify all input factors that impact the algorithm's complexity and specify them accordingly.

---

In your example, the space complexity can be indeed O(1) under the assumption that only the 26 English alphabets are used since it is constant and you will always allocate 26 slots for any inputs.

However, without this assumption, the space complexity could be O(n), where 'n' represents the number of elements in the set of possible characters and you could allocate more than 26 slots.

Also, even if the previous assumption holds, but if the input string can be very long and must be saved in the memory, then the space complexity could be O(n), where 'n' represents the length of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Statements of complexity are made about algorithms to *communicate* important performance properties of those algorithms.

You can make those statements in terms of whatever variables you like.

If you were to write the normal "most frequent character" algorithm for lowercase letters, for example, then you would normally say that it takes O(n) time and O(1) space.  You could specify that n is the length of the string, but you wouldn't need to, because that's the obvious variable to choose.  When it's not obvious, you do need to specify in order to communicate.

If you were to write the same algorithm, but accepting unrestricted Unicode strings, then you would probably say that it takes O(k) space, where k is the size of the alphabet used.  You *could* still say it takes O(1) space, but that *fails to communicate* information about its memory consumption that could be important in practice.

When the only use you've had for complexity statements is answering questions on tests, it's easy to forget their real-life purpose in the practical evaluation of algorithms.